# OrientDB Graph API: process results of SQL query

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop

I'm exploring ways of interacting with OrientDB graphs. I'm writing java code, so I'm using some kind of java API. Since tinkerpop is described as the "JDBC" of graph databases, I naively assumed there would be an equivalent of executing a query and then processing the result set.

From a graph, I can call something like:

```
graph.command(new OCommandSQL("SELECT FROM class")).execute();
```

Then what? The "execute" method returns an Object, not very helpful. By printing out the class name of the result object, it seems to be a "OrientDynaElementIterable", whatever that is.

So I'm not sure I understand how I run a query and then iterate over the results. In general I actually don't understand tinkerpop, as I'm dealing with a load of OrientDB specific classes that are curiously part of the tinkerpop specification, so how does that make my code portable across graph databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a graph command you retrieve an `Iterable` of `Vertex`.

```
for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command
                       (new OCommandSQL("SELECT FROM class").execute()) {
     // Do something with vertex v
}
```

---

The documentation can be retrieved [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#execute-commands) where you can find the following example

```
for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command(
            new OCommandSQL("SELECT EXPAND( out('bought') ) FROM Customer WHERE name = 'Jay'")).execute()) {
    System.out.println("- Bought: " + v);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that? I mean how do I actually even know that I'll get Vertex instances back, rather than anything else? I can find no documentation on this at all, and it seems like the most basic operation I'd want to do. Using the console is all very well for exploration, but in reality you need the API, and as far as I can see that's largely undocumented

Comment: @TomQuarendon I added a reference to the documentation in the answer

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that example. I've looked through loads of the documentation, but I missed that bit.